# Работа с NoSQL базой типа tarantool

Tags: python

Есть ли что то похожее на tarantool? а именно обработка огромного количества запросов за очень короткое время, но кроссплатформенное решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [redis](http://redis.io/) - key value хранилище, которое хранит данные в оперативной памяти, и по этому очень быстрое. Есть клиент для множества языков, в том числе [и для python](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)